# Skipping NA rows in index column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with a column with values TRUE and NA. I'd like to add an index column to the df that indexes all rows with TRUE but simply skips all rows with NA, without removing them. Like this:

```
VarA    ID
TRUE    1
NA      NA
NA      NA
TRUE    2
TRUE    3
```

At the moment I'm doing it as:

```
i = 1:nrow(df)
df$ID <- ifelse(df$VarA == TRUE, i, NA)
```

but that gives me

```
VarA    ID
TRUE    1
NA      NA
NA      NA
TRUE    4
TRUE    5
```

which is not what I want. I know this should be super easy with something like na.omit but somehow I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 4):

Using base R

```
df1$ID2[!is.na(df1$VarA)] <- seq_along(na.omit(df1$VarA))

  VarA ID ID2
1 TRUE  1   1
2   NA NA  NA
3   NA NA  NA
4 TRUE  2   2
5 TRUE  3   3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
# example dataset
df = data.frame(VarA = c(TRUE, NA, NA, TRUE, TRUE))

# get cumulative sum based on cases where you don't have NA in VarA
df$ID = cumsum(!is.na(df$VarA))

# if you have NA in VarA use NA instead ofthe cumulative sum
df$ID = ifelse(is.na(df$VarA), df$VarA, df$ID)

df

#   VarA ID
# 1 TRUE  1
# 2   NA NA
# 3   NA NA
# 4 TRUE  2
# 5 TRUE  3
```

You can combine the above in one command if you prefer like

```
df$ID = ifelse(is.na(df$VarA), df$VarA, cumsum(!is.na(df$VarA)))
```

Comment: Oh wow, thank you so much!! The cumsum function is actually EXACTLY what I needed. After creating the ID column, I've been filling in the NA variables of the ID column with na.locf() from the zoo package. I hadn't realised there was a way simpler way to do the whole procedure. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Using `tidyverse`, you can do this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(VarA) %>%
  mutate(counter = row_number(ID))
```

Output:

```
  VarA     ID counter
  <lgl> <int>   <int>
1 TRUE      1       1
2 NA       NA      NA
3 NA       NA      NA
4 TRUE      2       2
5 TRUE      3       3
```

Sample data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "VarA    ID
TRUE    1
           NA      NA
           NA      NA
           TRUE    2
           TRUE    3", header = TRUE,
           stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

One option in `base`:

```
transform(df, ID = replace(cumsum(!is.na(VarA)), is.na(VarA), NA))
```

Output:

```
   VarA ID
1: TRUE  1
2:   NA NA
3:   NA NA
4: TRUE  2
5: TRUE  3
```

Answer (score 1):

`data.table` solution

```
library( data.table )
DT <- data.table::fread("
VarA
TRUE
NA
NA
TRUE
TRUE")

DT[ !is.na(VarA), ID := .I][]
```

or

```
setDT(df)[ !is.na(VarA), ID := .I][]
```

results in

```
#    VarA ID
# 1: TRUE  1
# 2:   NA NA
# 3:   NA NA
# 4: TRUE  2
# 5: TRUE  3
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R solution using `which`

```
df$ID[which(df$VarA)]<-seq(which(df$VarA))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an index `i` holding `!is.na(df$VarA)` which can be used for subseting `df` and to generate the sequence.

```
i <- !is.na(df$VarA)
df$ID[i] <- seq_len(sum(i))
df
#  VarA ID
#1 TRUE  1
#2   NA NA
#3   NA NA
#4 TRUE  2
#5 TRUE  3
```

Or using `which` for the index:

```
i <- which(df$VarA)
df$ID[i] <- seq_along(i)
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(VarA = c(TRUE,NA,NA,TRUE,TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for looping or iterating:

```
df$ID <- ifelse(df$VarA == TRUE, TRUE, NA)
```

Should give you the desired result.

Or, maybe I missunderstood and you want to *remove* rows with `NA` in `VarA`:

```
df[!is.na(df$VarA), ]
```